# iterating over elements in a vector, wrapping around from the last element to the first element in a circular fashion

Tags: java, vector, iteration

I am attempting to iterate through a sorted vector object that contains randomly generated int values.  The idea is to visit each element, outputting its value, then moving on to the next element.

The problem is my iteration is only visiting/outputting EVERY OTHER element, rather than every element.  My code is as follows:

```
    //note 'tempRequests' is a vector object containing randomly generated 
    //int values 

    int i = 0;

    Collections.sort(tempRequests);

    System.out.println("request vector is now: ");
    System.out.println(tempRequests);

    Vector<Integer> requestCopy = new Vector<Integer>();
    requestCopy = tempRequests;


    //for (int i = currentPosition; i < tempRequests.size()-1; i++)
    while (requestCopy.size() > 0)
    {   
        if (requestCopy.contains(tempRequests.get(i)))
        {
            System.out.println("Processing " + tempRequests.get(i));
            requestCopy.removeElement(tempRequests.get(i));
        }

        if (i+1 <= tempRequests.size()-1)
            i++;
        else
            i = 0;  
    }
```

I'm getting the following output with different randomly generated int values:

```
request vector is now: 
[172, 548, 568, 632, 698, 779, 886, 950, 1011]
Processing 172
Processing 568
Processing 698
Processing 886
Processing 1011
Processing 548
Processing 779
Processing 632
Processing 950
Vector queue empty, consumer waiting...
```

I've tried adjusting the for loop but am not quite understanding why only every other element is visited.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does not do what you think it does:

```
Vector<Integer> requestCopy = new Vector<Integer>();
requestCopy = tempRequests;
```

`requestCopy = tempRequests` changes the `requestCopy` variable to refer to the **same** `Vector` object as the `tempRequests` variable, discarding the reference to the `Vector` object that was created in the preceding line.

What you meant to do was `requestCopy.addAll(tempRequests)` to **copy** the elements from the `tempRequests` vector to the new vector that was just created.

Better yet, use the copy-constructor:

```
Vector<Integer> requestCopy = new Vector<>(tempRequests);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since what you want to do is simply iterate over a Vector and print out the values rather than creating a copy and having to manage printing and removing elements from the copy, consider using an Iterator.

```
Iterator value = tempRequests.iterator();
while(value.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Processing: " + value.next());
}
```

The above four lines would replace all the code of creating the requestCopy Vector and the entire while loop you have.

Answer (score 1):

I think your requestCopy and tempRequests are two references to one vector object.

`Vector<Integer> requestCopy = new Vector<Integer>();`this line you created new vector and then you replace that new Vector Object with Object which reference to tempRequests .You can not copy Object that way.

remove `requestCopy = tempRequests;` and update `Vector<Integer> requestCopy = new Vector<Integer>();` to `Vector<Integer> requestCopy = new Vector<Integer>(tempRequests);`
and then it will work.

I hope that help you thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Modify your if from

```
if (requestCopy.contains(tempRequests.get(i))) {
    System.out.println("Processing " + tempRequests.get(i));      
    requestCopy.removeElement(tempRequests.get(i));
}
```

to

```
System.out.println("Processing " + tempRequests.get(i));
if (requestCopy.contains(tempRequests.get(i))) {
    requestCopy.removeElement(tempRequests.get(i))
}
```

Comment: `requestCopy` and `tempRequests` refer to the same vector object, so `requestCopy.contains(tempRequests.get(i))` cannot be false.